# CSS list-horizontal

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to copy this website template: [link](https://freewebsitetemplates.com/preview/rehabilitation-yoga/index.html)

I want to make the list items horizontal like in the link above, But it just doesnt work with `display:inline block` which is what I've seen from google and this forum, I also tried to use `float.`I have tried to search several ways including using a `table` but it doesn't work either.This is probably a stupid mistake Im overlooking but I can't seem to find a solution.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <a href="https://freewebsitetemplates.com/preview/rehabilitation-yoga/index.html">
      <h1>Belle & Carrie</h1>
    </a>
    <span>rehabilitation yoga
    </span>
  </div>

  <ul class="listHorizontal">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>




</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #077054;
  color: #315f52;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}
.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #99fa99;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-family: "latoregular";
}
.header span {
  color: #b6d8cf;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'nixie_oneregular';

}

.listHorizontal {

 color: #b6d8cf;
  font-size:30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;


}
```

Comment: try `display: inline` in your <li>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in following way:

```css
body {
  background: #077054;
  color: #315f52;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}
.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #99fa99;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-family: "latoregular";
}
.header span {
  color: #b6d8cf;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'nixie_oneregular';

}

.listHorizontal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: #b6d8cf;
  font-size:30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
   <div class="header">
    <a href="https://freewebsitetemplates.com/preview/rehabilitation-yoga/index.html">
      <h1>Belle & Carrie</h1>
    </a>
    <span>rehabilitation yoga
    </span>
  </div>

  <ul class="listHorizontal">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Why doesnt display-inline block doesnt work? I've never seen the justify-content or display: flex; elsewhere in the internet.

Comment: It's new display property (``flexbox``) introduced. You can find its specification https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Add this css, it will work

```
.listHorizontal li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `display:flex` the items align horizontally. You can then apply many more styles to the container or children to push the content around.

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
body {
  background: #077054;
  color: #315f52;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}
.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #99fa99;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-family: "latoregular";
}
.header span {
  color: #b6d8cf;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'nixie_oneregular';
}

.listHorizontal {
  color: #b6d8cf;
  font-size:30px;
  padding:0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style-type: none;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <a href="https://freewebsitetemplates.com/preview/rehabilitation-yoga/index.html">
      <h1>Belle & Carrie</h1>
    </a>
    <span>rehabilitation yoga
    </span>
  </div>

  <ul class="listHorizontal">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ``space-around`` instead of ``space-evenly``.

Comment: I think it depends on what you are going for. Any would work fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
.listHorizontal li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: So you have to specify it further with an li?