# How to customize HTML/CSS horizontal menu?

Tags: html, css

I had a vertical menu with submenus and decided to turn it to horizontal. I tried but it doesn't seem so well. How can I make it appear with bigger width and window centered? I know there are many errors, but how can I fix them?

I have done a huge web search and I haven't found something that it works. All the codes posted and marked as solutions even in here, Stack Overflow, are not working properly for me, at least locally that I use them as the whole thing will be running locally.

```js
function resizeIframe(obj) {
  obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}

function myFunction() {
  var year = document.getElementById("year");
  alert(year.options[year.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

```css
body
    {
        background-image: url('background.png');
    }
    .menu
    {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        text-align: left;
        position: fixed;
        width: auto;
    }
    a.parent, a.parent:hover/* attaches side-arrow to all parents */
    {

        background-image: url(nav_blue.png);

        background-position: right center;

        background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }

    .options {
    width: 100%;
    }

    .content {
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding: 1px 0px;
        height: auto;
        overflow:hidden;    
    }

    /* First Level */
    .menu ul
    {
        border: 1px solid rgba(55,55,155,0.5);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        display: inline-table;
        padding: 20px 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .menu ul li
    {    
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s Ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s Ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s Ease;
        position: relative; 
        float: left; 
    }
    .menu ul li:hover
    {
    
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(100,100,100,0.2), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    /* Hyperlink Style */
    .menu a
    {
        font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: rgba(0,200,255,0.3) 1px 1px 0px;
        display: block;
        padding: 20px 20px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align:center;
    }

    /* Drop down Levels */
    .menu ul ul
    {
        display: none;
        border-radius: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .menu ul li:hover > ul
    {
        display: inline-table;
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;

    }
    .menu ul ul li a
    {
        padding: 8px 20px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>page</title>
     <meta charset="ISO-8859-7"> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" target="content">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="content" class="parent">Fields</a>
<ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="content" class="parent">Link 22</a>
          <ul><li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="content">Another link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content"><iframe name="content" src="start.htm" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS list-horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512117/css-list-horizontal)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description. This will often show up in search results.">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Here is the header -->
    <header>
      <nav class="nav-header-main">
        <a class="header-logo" href="index.php">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fields</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
}

.wrapper-main {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-header-main {
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header-logo {
  width: 48px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.nav-header-main img {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-header-main ul {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-header-main ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-header-main ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #111;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: I do not know that it should show but here is what I saw with the latest version of Firefox and Chrome: https://imgur.com/a/lV6OXY3

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
function resizeIframe(obj) {
  obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}

function myFunction() {
  var year = document.getElementById("year");
  alert(year.options[year.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg');
}
.menu {
  top: 25%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
}
a.parent, a.parent:hover {
  background-image: url(https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.sm.jpg);
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.options {
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 1px 0px;
  height: auto;
  overflow:hidden;    
}
.menu ul {
  border: 1px solid rgba(55,55,155,0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  display: inline-table;
  padding: 20px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s Ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s Ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s Ease;
  position: relative;
  /* float: left; */
}
.menu ul li:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(100,100,100,0.2), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.menu a {
  font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: rgba(0,200,255,0.3) 1px 1px 0px;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: inline-table;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
}
.menu ul ul li a {
  padding: 8px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" target="content">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="content" class="parent">Fields</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>\
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" target="content" class="parent">Link 22</a>
      <ul><li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" target="content">Another link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- <div class="content"><iframe name="content" src="start.htm" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe></div> -->
```

Remove `float: left;` from style of `.menu ul li` to make the list vertical.

Give `top: 25%;` to `.menu` to bring the menu 25% down from top.